# Difficulties deploying a very small app from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, deployment

I've been developing using MSVC and C++ for a while, and I've been attempting to use Microsoft's extension for creating an installer for the program. However, it does not include the proper dependencies (namely msvcp140.dll). In the past I have manually found these files and included them, one at a time. The installer project also KNEW what DLLS I required, showed them to me, but didn't add them. It's a very small text based program with no dependencies other than standard lib. What should I do to create a functioning installer for my program? I'm very unfamiliar with this extension, unless someone has a better way to deploy :D

Comment: If you're building your installer with a "Setup.exe" included, you can add the "Visual C++ 14 Runtime Libraries" as a pre-requisite. There are a few questions about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I have resolved the problem, MSVC has a "detected dependency" folder for the install, but was erroneously clearing itself seemingly randomly upon build. Thank you for your help, I have since done further research into the Setup.exe.